# Using Apache Ranger as an external authorizer with Istio mesh

Tags: authorization, istio, envoyproxy, istio-sidecar, apache-ranger

Iam new to Apache Ranger as well as Istio mesh. I have been trying to understand how to integrate Apache Ranger with Istio mesh as an external authorizer. As far as I have seen in the [documentation](https://istio.io/latest/docs/tasks/security/authorization/authz-custom/) and [articles](https://preliminary.istio.io/latest/blog/2021/better-external-authz/), Istio has provied a custom action to use an external authorizer which can forward requests to Apache Ranger.

The problem for me is that I'm using the ranger-plugin library to construct the request as mentioned here and do audit as well. So before the request goes to ranger for verification, I construct the request using the library and audit the data. Is there anyway I can accomodate this logic as part of the envoy-proxy?

Can someone help me understand the proper way of achieving this?